# Where is the style for WordPress image class wp-image-####?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

It seems whenever I insert an image to a WordPress post, it will add the following tag:

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-41880" src="https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/photoshop-certification-introduction.jpg" alt="Photoshop Certification Introduction " width="600" height="343" />
```

But in Chrome DevTools, I try to search for the style of wp-image-41880 but cannot find any. So what is the usage of this class wp-image-41880? Also what is the meaning of the digits 41880?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why `wp-image-41880` is added as a class to your img tag.
It's a feature of wordpress. the `41880` is the attachment ID of the image in the database.
This class is generated by WordPress to identify and style each image in a post.

By default there is no style defined by that class name, but you may want to chagne style of one of images in your post.

let's say you have 2 different image in a page, each one has its own class, e.g. `wp-image-41880` and `wp-image-41881`, you can easily change style of each image by their auto generated class name.

you may find other class names that generate by wordpress, e.g. in `body` (it depends on your theme) tag of a single blog post there are classes like `single` and `postid-1111` (1111 is just an example, it's related to post id in your DB).

Answer (score -1):

These numbers are the references created to process the image using javascript.

```
var elements = document. getElementsByClassName('wp-image-41880')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName